# When Cassandra is bootstrapping a new node, does that node serve read requests?

Tags: cassandra

I remember reading about it somewhere but cannot find it in the official docs anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anthony Grasso of The Last Pickle wrote an article on this about a year ago: [Bootstrapping Apache Cassandra Nodes](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/05/23/auto-bootstrapping-part1.html)  In it, he stated:

> ...the new node will accept new writes for the token ranges acquired while existing data from the other nodes is being streamed to it. This ensures that no new writes are missed while data changes hands. ... Once the bootstrapping process for the new node completes, it will begin to serve read requests.

So you are correct, that a bootstrapping node will *not* serve read requests until the bootstrapping process is complete.

Comment: Thanks! It's surprising that cannot be found in the official docs.

Comment: Follow-up question and for curiosity, is there a way to configure a node to serve read requests only when all the repairs are complete on the node?

Comment: What is the behaviour when RF is 1? New writes go to the new node and read for any new row key would return 'not found' kind of response?